# Appending Xml Data to List View JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am unable Show Parsed Response from Xml Service in JQuery Mobile List View. I unable to get were the Problem is,what i have Tried is.
First i took all the Response to theXML var then iam Trying to append to ListView Which i have Dynamically Created in javaScript Code. Here is my Code,

```
function processXML(theXML) {
  var nodeTree = theXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('Employee');
  var output = "";
  output += "<ul data-role='listview' class='ui-listview'>";
  var length = nodeTree.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var empName = nodeTree[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var empFName = nodeTree[i].getElementsByTagName('Fathername')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var empAddr = nodeTree[i].getElementsByTagName('Address')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    output += buildRow(empName, empFName, empAddr);
  }
  output += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output;
}

function buildRow(empName, empFName, empAddr) {
  var row = "<li><a href='#'>";
  row += empName;
  row += empFName;
  row += empAddr;
  row += "</a></li>";
  return row;
}
```

Comment: $("result").html(output).trigger("create");$(".ui-listview").listview('refresh');

Answer (score 0):

```
$("result").html(output).trigger("create");
$(".ui-listview").listview('refresh')‌​;
```